# Write working iterated variables via loop with jQuery/javascript

Tags: jquery, foreach, var

Using jQuery, how should I write a forEach style loop function where on each interation, the actual number of a variable name increases (and still works!)?

As I understand it, this can be done with "eval", but apparently is bad practice because it slows everything down - especially in a loop.

What's an alternative method? i.e. So the result is essentially:

> var1 = ((var1a) * foo) + var1b;
>
> var2 = ((var2a) * foo) + var2b;
>
> var3 = ((var3a) * foo) + var3b;
>
> var4 = ((var4a) * foo) + var4b;

Comment: We really need more info about your functions / data. The question you have now is really vague (and I have no idea what the "result" is that you list at the bottom). Adding the `eval` version would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to curry?

Comment: Hi, I don't think any the current answers are really covering it. Should I resubmit? The key issue is for me, is how can I run a for each loop where the iterated variables are still funcitonal as variables, even though they have been constructed -with iteration numbers - by the loop. Is this the essential syntax: "variable[i++]=((var[i++]a)*foo)+var[i++]b;" ?? I would love to provide a working example, but I don't know how to build one.

Answer (score 0):

Use ECMAscripts *bracket notation* to access properties or methods within an object.

```
var foo = {
    meth1: function() {},
    meth2: function() {},
    meth3: function() {}
};

Object.keys( foo ).forEach(function( name ) {
    foo[ name ]();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of this incorrectly. You shouldn't ever need to be dependent on the name of a function to tell you the results. You should be passing parameters into a single function that handles that for you.

You would instead do:

```
function doStuff(data, foo) { ... }

result = 0;
result += doStuff(someData1, operation);
result += doStuff(someData2, operation);
```

You could also extend doStuff with an additional parameter like `startingPoint` if you needed to pass in the value of result to operate on it.

```
function doStuff(data, foo, startingPoint) { ... }

result = 0;
result += doStuff(someData1, operation, result);
result += doStuff(someData2, operation, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do that rather than to create a normal function and pass the function number to it:

```
var data = {{data1a,data1b,data1c},{data2a,data2b,data2c}};
function myFunction(functionNumber){
    return data[functionNumber][0] * foo + data[functionNumber[1]; //functionNumber is 0 based
}
```

but assuming your actual situation makes a bit more sense  than your example, perhaps something like:

```
var functions = {};
var data ={}; //adjust for data source like {dataA = data1A, dataB=data1B};
var i = 1;
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    functions[i++] = ((key) * foo) + value;
});
```